# return first item / iteration in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list with several strings

```
myList = ['someFileName_red', 'someFileName_blue_v006', 'someFileName_green_v004']
```

I want to use this list as a search criteria to find image sequences with matching names on my server. These image sequences are located in all over the place on the server.

The root directory from which I will start my search is:

```
rootPath = r'C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq'
```

I'm trying to create a for loop that searches the volume by the **myList** and **rootPath** variables,but am finding it difficult to return the result of the for loop as the first item in the loop. Here's and example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for x in shotList:
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith(x):
                if file.endswith('.exr'):
                    print os.path.join(root,file)
```

Which returns:

```
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0101.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0102.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0103.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0104.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0105.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0101.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0102.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0103.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0104.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0105.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0106.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0107.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0101.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0102.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0103.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0104.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0105.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0106.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0107.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0108.exr
```

What I want to get back is the first frame of the image sequences:

```
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\images\someFileName_red.0101.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_blue\V006\Images\someFileName_blue_v006.0101.exr
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\Seq\shot\someFileName_green\V004\Images\someFileName_green_v004.0101.exr
```

Comment: Just taking your example, you could add a `break` statement after the `print` statement which will break out of the inner loop (and therefore continue the outer one). However if you have multiple image sequences that match the same name, they will be skipped too. So this really depends on your specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `break` after printing the first file and bellow:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for x in shotList:
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith(x) and file.endswith('.exr'):
                print os.path.join(root,file)
                break
```